# Usage du verbe "troller"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, registre, internet

Peut-on utiliser le verbe "troller" couramment ? Son emploi est-il acceptable dans tous les registres ?

Comment: On le dit pas, car troller c’est trop laid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, le verbe "troller" est employé couramment en France. C'est un néologisme qui est l'equivalent de "to troll" en anglais:

> Troller: créer artificiellement une controverse qui focalise
> l'attention, aux dépens des échanges et de l'équilibre habituel de la
> communauté

Référence: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)

Comment: @dimitris: [Troller, trôler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/troller) a aussi une une signification qui est, elle, bien plus ancienne.

Comment: Je pense que le terme "couramment" est un peu exagéré et doute qu'en dehors de la communauté geek (au sens large) le terme soit compris. D'ailleurs, on voit que le terme est moins usité sur lemonde depuis quelques années... Est-ce qu'il est passé de mode ? (source google : troller site:lefigaro.fr)

Comment: Disons qu'il est employé en Français aussi couramment qu'en Anglais, où là aussi il n'est compris que par les membres assidus de communautés en ligne comme les forums and réseaux sociaux.